# C++ Operator Precedence and Associativity problem

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
int n = 5, p = 9 ;
int q ;
q= p % n + p > n ;
```

I think q should be equal 5. But when i run the code, I found that q=1.

I don't understand the reason.

Comment: Why do you think it should be 5?

Comment: because the other operators take precedence over >, landing you with 4 + 9 = 13 before evaluating >, and 13 > 5 is a boolean expression and is only ever 0 or 1.  You need parentheses around `p > n` if you want 5.

Comment: Where would you put parentheses to reflect your assumption?

Comment: There was a tool — now gone (*sad panda*) — called Parenthesizer that add parens to an expression to show what the compiler is seeing.  It would have been very handy in this situation.

Comment: You need to add an explanation of *why* you think the answer should have been 5, as opposed to some other number, otherwise the issue you have is not reproducible, and not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the [operator precedence list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and tag each operator in your expression:

```
    q = p % n + p > n ;
//        5   6   9      <- precedence
```

With those tags in place, add parantheses, starting with the lowest number in the precedence list to see how your expression is interpreted:

```
    q = ((p % n) + p) > n;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need close parentheses well for each operation based on the requirement.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n = 5, p = 9;
    int q;
    q = (p % n) + (p > n);
    std::cout << q << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "for each operation" - no, only for the ambiguous ones (notably mixed && and ||) or where you need a precedence that doesn't align with the standard. You don't need parentheses around p % n, because % has higher precedence than +. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @Zoe — there are no ambiguous operations here. Just operations whose precedence leads to results that people sometimes find surprising. Similarly. `a && b || c && d` is not ambiguous, despite certain compilers warning you that you might not be smart enough to understand what it means. Interestingly, those compilers don’t warn you about `a * b + c * d`, even though the precedence works out exactly the same as the other one.

Answer (score -2):

1. `p % n = 9 % 5 = 4`
2. `4 + p = 4 + 9 = 13`
3. `13 > n = 13 > 5 = 1`
   Therefore q = 1.